# Error: Call to a member function getId() on string in file

Tags: php, zoho

I'm trying to insert notes in Zoho Contact Module, but getting an error `Error: Call to a member function getId() on string in file`. I'm working on a laravel project and inserted Zoho library [zoho
/
zcrm-php-sdk](https://github.com/zoho/zcrm-php-sdk)
I've passed all required parameters to the function but getting error in file this file line number 74 - [OrganizationAPIHandler.php](https://github.com/zoho/zcrm-php-sdk/blob/master/src/crm/api/handler/OrganizationAPIHandler.php)

**my code:**

```
$noteInstances = array(
            "Note_Title" => "Membership Updates",
            "Note_Content" => "Your membership get updated",
            "Parent_Id" => $zoho_id,
            "se_module" => "Contacts"
        );
        $notes = ZohoManager::currentOrg();
        $note = $notes->createNotes($noteInstances);
```

Comment: There is no `getId()` in your code here. Where exactly is the error coming from?

Comment: It looks like createNotes wants an array of instances. You're just sending it a single array, so when it tries to iterate through it, it's trying to run getId on the strings inside of your array. I don't know if encapsulating that inside of another array will work or not, since it will try to run member functions on the array.